# Quasi-Periodic Function as the Sum of Periodic Functions

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, special-functions, periodic-functions, quasiperiodic-function

Define $$f(x)=\frac{\cos^2(\pi x)}{2+\cos(x)}$$
We know that $f(x)$ is not periodic. Is there any way to write $f(x)$ as the sum of two periodic functions. That is, find periodic functions $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ such that $f(x)=f_1(x)+f_2(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Suppose $f=f_1+f_2$, where $f_1$ has period $p_1$ and $f_2$ has period $p_2$. Then $$f(x+p_1)=f_1(x+p_1)+f_2(x+p_1) = f_1(x)+f_2(x+p_1),$$ and $$f(x+p_1+p_2)=f_1(x+p_2)+f_2(x+p_1);$$ similarly, $$f(x+p_2)=f_1(x+p_2)+f_2(x),$$ for all $x$.  Combining these, we see that for all $x$, we have $$ f(x+ p_1+p_2)-f(x+p_2)-f(x+p_1)+f(x)=0.\tag{*}$$

After clearing fractions in (*) you get a non-trivial trigonometric polynomial that vanishes for all values of $x$.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you please add more details. I did not get why the sum that you wrote is equal to 0.

Comment: @Arthur The explanations about the first identity are given after it.

Comment: @JeanMarie I have rewritten my answer to make the argument a little more direct.  In fairness to Arthur, I had no explanation of my (*) when he posted his comment; my edits were in response to his comment.

Comment: I just wrote an explanation that uses Fourier Transform. @arthur : I am conscious that this explanation must be very difficult to follow. But maybe it can have a triggering effect on you as it had, long years ago, on me "I have to understand this fascinating domain" (called harmonic analysis) :)

Comment: Thanks for the comments!